# using wp_get_recent_posts() and the_content() at the same time using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the latest Wordpress post on the top of my website and below this post, I'm trying to display the content of the selected page. e.g. if the user is on "Home", on the top it should display the latest post and below it should display the content of "Home". To get the latest post I'm using `wp_get_recent_posts()` and to display the page content I'm using `the_content()`.

This is my code for the latest post:

```
<div id="news">
    <?php
        $posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'post'));

        foreach($posts as $post){
            echo '<p>' . $post["post_content"] . '</p>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

And to show the page content I'm using this code:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
<div id="postcontent">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

My problem is: It doesn't show the page content. If I comment the "news" part, it shows the page content. It seems those code parts cannot work at the same time. Are there any alternatives or is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_get_recent_posts()` just like `get_posts` and `get_pages` just returns post objects from a custom instance of `WP_Query`, and not the complete query object. What this means is, you cannot use the default query object that is returned by `WP_Query` to run a normal loop, therefor no postdata is setup by default using either of the first three functions.

Setting up postdata is very important as this makes the use of template tags available. As you do or do not know, setting up postdata requires the `$post` global to be set up (*Note: Any other variable will not work*), so this is what we will use. (*Note: Do not use the `$posts` global as a variable, you are breaking that global*)

```
$args = [
    // Some arguments
];
$posts_array = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post ); // This is the important line, and you have to use $post
    the_content();
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // Very important, restores the $post global
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It works as expected. I noticed that another alternative for my code would be renaming `$posts` and `$post`.

Comment: Sorry, got carried away with `get_posts`

Comment: If you stick with your method yes, but if you use `setup_postdata`, you must use `$post` ;-)

Comment: Doesn't matter. It works both ways. If I rename those variables to some random variable name, `setup_postdata()` and `wp_reset_postdata()` aren't necessary anymore. Is this because then the global variables aren't overwritten anymore?

Comment: That would be correct. Just remember, in the way you are using your post content, it is unfiltered, so just be causious about that. That is why I either use `setup_postdata` or in your example use `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post["post_content"]);` to apply filtering to the post content ;-)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: When using `wp_get_recent_posts()`, it is important to set the `$output` argument to `OBJECT`, otherwise `setup_postdata()` will not work (because `$post` must be an instance of `\WP_Post`).

Answer (score 0):

When you do this :

```
foreach($posts as $post)
```

You're overwriting the global `$post` object.

Use `wp_reset_postdata()` right after your loop so it will reset the `$post` object to the one of the main query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `wp_reset_postdata()` doesn't work as expected. Any other suggestions?